# Is there a way to globally set the math font style?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

Specifically, I am using complex numbers and I would like my z to look like one would write it on paper. That is, with a bar through the middle. So my question is twofold. Does there exist a font in latex that has this bar and how do I set this such that this font is used in all math environments in my documents. A working example would be as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        z=a+ib
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Either there's such a symbol or define a command that uses this font for the symbol, say `\myz`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first trial with logical markup, so make a consistent notation, defining `\myz` to be the (uppercase!) `\mathcal{Z}` letter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\myz}{\mathcal{Z}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
      \myz=a+ib
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps with my current document. I guess this is the closest we can get without a global setting. There is probably simply no font that solves this problem by itself. Thanks again.

Comment: @Justsomeone: I don't know at the moment. Perhaps you should give us a example how this z - letter should look like.